# Question regarding 'Invalid Type' on a List

Tags: query

I keep getting an "Invalid type: Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c" error on this line :

```
private List<Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c> newRecords = new List<Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c>();
```

for this class below (line 10):

```
AddSubsidiariesAndBrands extension
where Contract_Terms__r.Account__c = 
public with sharing class AddSubsidiariesAndBrands {

    private static String CLIENT_COUNTRY_PROILE_PREFIX = Client_Profile__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    private static String CONTRACT_TERMS_PREFIX = Contract_Terms__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
    private static String CLIENT_COUNTRY_PROILE = 'CCP';
    private static String CONTRACT_TERMS = 'CO';


    private String parentId;
    private String parentAccountId;
    private List<Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c> newRecords = new List<Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c>();
    private Client_Profile__c clientProfile;
    private String contractTerms;
    private String objectType;

    public AddSubsidiariesAndBrands() {
        this.parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        // For some reason 'id; returns null when the grid is loaded in the 
        // Client Country Profile record detail, but 'myid' returns the id
        if (this.parentId == null) {
            this.parentId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myid');
        }

        if (this.parentId.startsWith(CLIENT_COUNTRY_PROILE_PREFIX)) {
            this.objectType = CLIENT_COUNTRY_PROILE;
            List<Client_Profile__c> ccps = [SELECT id, Account_Name__c, Contract_Overview__c FROM Client_Profile__c WHERE Id = : this.parentId OR Id = :parentId];

            if (!ccps.isEmpty()) {
                this.parentAccountId = ccps[0].Account_Name__c;
                this.contractTerms = ccps[0].Contract_Terms__c;
            }
        } else if (this.parentId.startsWith(CONTRACT_TERMS_PREFIX)) {
            this.objectType = CONTRACT_TERMS;
            Contract_Terms__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, cos.Contract_Terms__r.Account__c FROM Contract_Terms__c WHERE Id = : this.parentId];

            if (!cos.isEmpty()) {
                this.parentAccountId = cos[0].Account__c;
            } 
        }
    }

    public AddSubsidiariesAndBrands(ApexPages.StandardController pController) {
    }

    public PageReference init() {
        String vfPage;

        String idsString = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
        this.parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myid');

        if (idsString != null) {

            List<String> idsStrings = idsString.split(',');
            List<Id> ids = (List<Id>)idsStrings;

            try {

                if (this.objectType == CLIENT_COUNTRY_PROILE) {
                    vfPage = 'ClientCountryProfileGridInclude';

                    for (Id newId : ids) {
                        Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c newRecord = new Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c(Client_Country_Profile__c = this.parentId,
                                                                                                        Serviced_Subsidiaries_and_Brands__c = newId,
                                                                                                        Agreement__c = this.contractTerms); 
                        this.newRecords.add(newRecord);                                                                               
                    }

                } else if (this.objectType == CONTRACT_TERMS) {
                    vfPage = 'contractTermsGridInclude';

                    for (Id newId : ids) {
                        Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c newRecord = new Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c(Agreement__c = this.parentId,
                                                                                                        Serviced_Subsidiaries_and_Brands__c = newId); 
                        this.newRecords.add(newRecord);                                                                               
                    }

                }

                if (!newRecords.isEmpty()) {
                    insert this.newRecords;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ApexPages.Message successMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Save Failure!');
                ApexPages.addMessage(successMsg);
                System.debug('***ex: ' + ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        PageReference returnPage = new PageReference('/apex/' + vfPage + '?id=' + this.parentId);
        return returnPage;
    }

    public PageReference add() {
        PageReference returnPage = new PageReference('/apex/GBLiteSandbox__grid?gname=Select Subsidiaries and Brands ' 
                                                     + this.objectType + '&sh=0&ssb=0&sbb=1&fpf=Parent_Account__c&fpv=' 
                                                     + this.parentAccountId
                                                     + '&myid=' + this.parentId);
        return returnPage;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return this.parentId;    
    }

    public void setParentId(String pValue) {
        this.parentId = pValue;    
    }

//***TEST METHODS***//

    @isTest
    private static void test_constructor_contractTerms() {
        //add required fields for Contract_Terms__c
        Contract_Terms__c co = new Contract_Terms__c();
        //insert once required fields are met
        //insert co;
        PageReference pageRef = new ApexPages.StandardController(co).view();

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', co.Id);

        //Test id param
        AddSubsidiariesAndBrands testConstructor = new AddSubsidiariesAndBrands();

        //Test myId param

        //Add some asserts

    }

}
```

I'm also attempting to pull the value of the Account__c from a related Object in one of those queries by doing this :

```
Contract_Terms__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, cos.Contract_Terms__r.Account__c FROM Contract_Terms__c WHERE Id = : this.parentId];
```

Can somebody please help me on these two errors ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Try `cos.Contract_Terms__r.Account__r.Id` for the second. For the first, are you sure you have the object's API name correct and that there isn't a typo?

Comment: You're right - it was the API name :-/

Thanks Mike !

Comment: I think the other one is gonna work. I can see what you're doing. Thanks again Mike. You're really a great help !

Comment: @MikeChale - I tried that same method, but I'm now getting an error telling me "Didn't understand relationship 'cos' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name". I know I am using the proper child relationship names and field. Do you have any idea what might be the right way ? Thanks again.

Comment: Could you do us a favor...? Go to Setup > Schema Builder, and lay out the following objects: Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c, Contract_Terms__c, and Client_Profile__c. Without knowing how your fields are laid out, we can't accurately diagnose your code. It's not even compilable, so we know there are relationship issues.

Answer (score 3):

> I keep getting an "`Invalid type: Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c`" error on this line :

Make sure that `Subsidiaries_Brands_Serviced__c` is the correct API name. You should consult Setup > Create > Objects and make sure you don't have a typo. Also, the namespace is required if the object is in a managed package that the code itself doesn't belong to.

> I'm also attempting to pull the value of the `Account__c` from a related Object in one of those queries by doing this:

You're using an alias (`cos`) without aliasing the table. Your query appears to be incorrect. You probably meant to use:

```
Contract_Terms__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, Account__c FROM Contract_Terms__c WHERE Client_Profile__c = :this.parentId];
```

Although it's hard to tell, because it's just not right.

FYI, there's a better way to do your comparison check:

```
if (this.parentId.getSObjectType() == Client_Profile__c.SObjectType) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// For some reason 'id; returns null when the grid is loaded in the 
// Client Country Profile record detail, but 'myid' returns the id
```

I see the others have helped you with the rest of your question. I believe this part is because you have sharing enabled for the class

```
public with sharing class AddSubsidiariesAndBrands {
```

Until Apex knows the context of the user, it can't determine the Client's Country Profile record detail. Otherwise, and I'm not entirely certain on this, I believe it would default to the company's country profile since it wouldn't be asked to make any assumptions about the country profile for the user.

Hope this points you in the right direction to solving that part of your puzzle. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For traversing relationships in SOQL, the format is `relationship_name__r.FieldName`, so in your query:

> Contract_Terms__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, cos.Contract_Terms_*r.Account*_c FROM Contract_Terms__c WHERE Id = : this.parentId];

The first relationship is `Contract_Terms__r` and the second is likely `Account__r` (unless you specifically renamed it) so your query should probably be:

> Contract_Terms__c[] cos = [SELECT Id, Contract_Terms__r.Account__.Id FROM Contract_Terms__c WHERE Id = : this.parentId];

This is saying:

- Start with the Contract_Terms__c object
- Follow the Contract_Terms__r lookup
- Then the Account__r lookup
- Get me the Account id.

Comment: `Account__c` and `Account__r.Id` are the same; except if you query `Account__c` but not `Account__r.Id`, you'd get an error if you referenced `Account__r.Id` (NPE), and the same if you queried `Account__r.Id` but referenced `Account__c` (FNQ).

Comment: Mike - yes, I understand that logic. But for some reason I am getting that error which says 'don't understand relationship cos ' if I use cos.Contract_Terms__r.Account__c or if I use just Contract_Terms__r.Account__c the error will say 'don't understand relationship Contract_Terms__r'.

Comment: @sfdcfox - is it possible that I could be getting this error because there are multiple child relationships named Contract_Terms__r on the object ?

Comment: In the cos query, you're trying to get Contract_Terms__r.Account__c, which would only be valid if Contract_Terms__c had a field called Contract_Terms__c (in other words, if the Contract_Terms__c object had a lookup relationship to itself).

Comment: I am attempting to get the value of the Account__c field in another object which Contract_Terms__c has a lookup field relationship with - and that child relationship name is Contract_Terms__r. So is that not the correct syntax ?

Comment: @Zoom_v: Check your WSDL (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm) to find the correct name. If you have multiple relationships with the same name then you'll want to change one so that they're unique.

Comment: @sfdcfox: What are NPE and FNQ?

Comment: NPE is Null Pointer Exception, FNQ is Field Not Queried. I think this means I've officially been developing too long in Apex Code...